# $ cdk synth 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to create cloudformation Stack using CDK in python .I have checked Python is installed with version 3.7.
But still , after running cdk synth command i am getting below error.Path variable is already set to python .

$ cdk synth
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it should be `python3`?

Comment: you don't need to pass 'python' to `cdk synth`. What do you get when you just run `cdk synth`?